# Draggable navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm pretty new here so apologize my vocabulary.
I'm trying to navigate in my website with drag function like this site : https://stimulation.zone
I tried to make this with jquery but I understand how elements can be draggable but not make like this website, have you got an idea or a purpose to me with jquery for example, thanks for reading.
Have a good day !

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: You may want to review https://stimulation.zone/assets/deploy/CDN_PATH/js/main.js?v=202105313 as many of the Libraries are referenced here. This might give you a better starting point than trying to develop your own, possibly complex, code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.